# Rounding aggregated results in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have build a JPA Query to perform an aggregate using sum of a column as below:

```
 @Repository
 public interface PersonRepository extends JPARepository<Person, Long>{
 @Query(value = "select sum(salary)/15 from Person where salaryDate between :fromDate and :toDate and name = :name group by name")
Long getAggregatedSalary(@Param("name") String name, @Param("fromDate") Date fromDate, @Param("toDate") Date toDate)
    
}


@Entity
@TableName(name = "Person")
@Data
class Person implements Persistable{
  @Id
  Long id;
  Integer salary;
  String name
}
```

The aggregation performed in the query can give a decimal value for ex. 102.34.
However when the JPA returns the result, it converts the calculated value to 102 instead of  giving me decimal values.
I tried changing the return type of the JPA function to Long and Double, but no luck.

Comment: Is this due to the division? JPA requires SUM to return long when operating on longs, but for arithmetic expressions states: "otherwise, if there is an operand of type Long or long, the result of the operation is of type Long, unless the operator is / (division), in which case the numeric result type is not further defined;" (section 4.8.6, jpa 3.0). You might be better performing the '/15' operation in your client on the results directly and see if it helps, or determine what type the database/driver is returning for this operation through JDBC statements.

Comment: I guess you are right. I need to perform the division post getting result from the query.